# AngularJs: Issue Getting Jsons from factory corresponding to $routeParams

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to have `$scope.lessons` get `/writeups/example.json` when a user navigates to `/tutorials/example`.

My `app.js` file has html5 mode enabled, and looks like:

```
.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
.when('/tutorials/:topic', {templateUrl: 'views/default.html', controller: 'AppCtrl'})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
```

I currently have in my controller

`$scope.lessons = LessonService.get({topic: $routeParams.topic});`

And my factory looks like:

```
app.factory('LessonService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('writeups/:topic.json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{topic:'bc'}, isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

**Update**: Here's my full controller

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'LessonService', '$routeParams', '$mdSidenav', '$timeout','$log', function($scope, $routeParams, LessonService, $mdSidenav, $timeout, $log) {
    function toggleSideNav(name){
        $mdSidenav(name).toggle();
    }

    function selectLesson(name){
        $scope.page = name.Path;
        $scope.toggleSideNav('left');
    }

    $scope.lessons = LessonService.LessonService.get({topic: $routeParams.topic});
    $scope.orderProp = 'Id';
    $scope.toggleSideNav = toggleSideNav;
    $scope.selectLesson = selectLesson;
    $scope.page = 'views/defaultLesson.html';
}]);
```

Comment: What gets returned when you look in Developer Tools on the Network tab for that request? I suspect your server routing configuration is not quite right.

Comment: It looks like I'm getting this error: Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Comment: Just got it; thanks for the advice to use the dev tools. The issue was that I was using 'get' instead of 'query'. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using 'get' instead of 'query'. Thanks a bunch for your help, gregL! This mistake wasted so much time :'(

`$scope.lessons = LessonService.query({topic: $routeParams.topic});`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to include $routeParams in your controller like this:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
     .controller('yourCtrl',["$scope", "$routeParams", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
      console.log($routeParams)

}]);
```

Comment: I did; I'll update the question with the full controller